# How to write rule in laravel version 5+

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using laravel 5+ and I wrote a rule in web.php file

```
 Route::get('cms/about-us', 'CmsController@index');
```

to access the index method on CmsController. But this rule does not work and gives error

> Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\CmsController::index()

Comment: Share you controller code also

Comment: Are you have index() function ?

Comment: public function index($params){
  
  echo "====".$params;
 }

Comment: Controller methods must return something, you're just echoing.